# USB powered Headphone Amplifier/Splitter w/ Separate Volume Control

Tags: audio, amplifiers, splitters

I need something similar to what James asked [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/501/portable-headphone-amplifier-splitter-w-separate-volume-control), e.g. a headphone amp/splitter with separate output volume controls and 3.5 jacks for in and outs, but I have slight different needs:

1. it must be USB powered or removable battery powered, no rechargeable lithium battery accepted here
2. it must have at least 3 jack outputs with their respective volume knobs
3. if nothing else exists, it can be a whole USB soundcard, because I'm going to use it only connected to a computer.

I've searched several times, but either I'm not searching with correct terms, or such a product does not exist at all. All my searches ended up with the FiiO E6 at best, which is not what I'm looking for, because it's only two outputs and it uses internal lithium rechargeable battery.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't do DIY recommendations here, so I've edited that part of your question out.

Comment: What has your research turned up?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths absolutely nothing, that's why I included seek for DIY solutions that I didn't know aren't acceptable here

Comment: You have to show a little effort on your part.